# dotnet tool aspnet-codegenerator looks for executable at wrong path

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm currently following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=netcore-cli#scaffold-identity-into-an-empty-project) in order to scaffold Identity in my existing ASP.NET Core project. When trying to run the scaffolder command with the help option, though, I'm getting this error message:

```
> dotnet aspnet-codegenerator --help
The application to execute does not exist: 'C:\Users\Tim\.dotnet\tools\.store\dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator\2.2.0-rtm-35687\dotnet-aspnet-codegener
ator\2.2.0-rtm-35687\tools\netcoreapp2.1\any\dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator.dll'.
```

I've checked the .dotnet\tools.store directory and the tool seems to be installed correctly. BUT, it is installed in a `2.2.0` directory instead of the `2.2.0-rtm-35687` directory, which `dotnet tool` is looking in.

I've tried uninstalling the tool again and installing it again; updating .NET Core (now at v2.2.100), but it didn't help. Is there a way to configure where `dotnet tool` will look for globally installed tools?

Comment: what does `dotnet --version` show you?

Comment: It shows `2.2.100`.

Comment: did you setup a global.json at any point in the past? have you tried the tool from other locations?

Comment: Nope and nope. I've opened an issue on GitHub some days ago and it seems to be a bug. Follow it here: https://github.com/aspnet/Scaffolding/issues/932

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug, which got solved in the meantime. Read more about it here: https://github.com/aspnet/Scaffolding/issues/932

Answer (score 5):

Just change the folder name from "2.2.0" to "2.2.0-rtm-35687" in both the places inside the c:\users\.dotnet\tools.store\dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator folder and
c:\users\.dotnet\tools.store\dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator\2.2.0-rtm-35687\dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator folder

Now try to run the command. It works for me.

P.S: I am not much sure how this is going to affect other areas so far not detected any

Comment: While this solution will probably work, it is rather unsatisfying. Renaming folders after installing a tool automatically should not be necessary.

Comment: I also came across this issue - how can we report this as a bug?